# Laptop shutdown while booting Ubuntu and then won't turn on

Tags: hardware

My Lenovo Ideapad, while I was booting Ubuntu (it was loading the boot image), suddenly stopped and turned off.

From that time I'm not able to turn on that laptop and when I plugged the charger it was not showing the led light. I don't know what to do can you please tell me what to do.

Comment: IF the system 'suddenly' shut down and you plugin the charger and don't get any type of indication the power is working, that's a hardware issue, especially if the computer won't turn on, and you need to get support from Lenovo to test/replace the hardware that's affected.  (Hardware support of this nature tends to be too hard to support here on Ask Ubuntu)

Comment: A fried motherboard is the most likely. Memory and disk allow booting up to a point and then crash. Not doing anything is more motherboard related.

Comment: More than likely, your AC adapter has gone bad, or you're lost your AC, and you didn't notice it, until your remaining battery died. Try another AC adapter. Or... try this... remove the AC adapter and battery, and hold down the POWER button for 15 seconds. Reconnect the battery and AC adapter, and see if it works again. Report back to @heynnema